# Index pages in a react application and naming conventions with folder structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, naming-conventions

I'm really trying to get an idea from other Javascript developers opinion on file name and structure. My main concern is using the file name index.tsx(or js) inside a lone folder if there would be issues if a fellow developer were to come in and pick up where I left off.

Below is the file structure I currently have and you can see that each page and component is separated into its own folder and using the index.tsx naming convention. Should for example the About page have the file name and folder structure of "./About/about.tsx" or does the naming convention I have in place now work just fine of "./About/index.tsx"?

Only real difference I can see is when importing the file into another it'll have a slightly longer file path.

````html
├─ src
│  ├─ App.tsx
│  ├─ components
│  │  ├─ ArrowIcon
│  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  ├─ Footer
│  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  ├─ FormError
│  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  ├─ Header
│  │  │  ├─ header.module.css
│  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ Logo
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  └─ Navigation
│  │  │     ├─ PrimaryNav.tsx
│  │  │     ├─ SecondaryNav.tsx
│  │  │     └─ styles.module.css
│  │  ├─ IntroHeader
│  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  ├─ Layout
│  │  │  ├─ Container
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  ├─ index.module.css
│  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  └─ PageHeader
│  │     ├─ index.tsx
│  │     └─ styles.module.css
│  ├─ Content
│  │  ├─ Configuration
│  │  │  └─ ConfigurationHome.ts
│  │  ├─ Footer
│  │  │  └─ footer.json
│  │  ├─ Home
│  │  │  ├─ About.json
│  │  │  ├─ FAQ.ts
│  │  │  └─ Tutorial.json
│  │  ├─ Navigation
│  │  │  └─ index.ts
│  │  ├─ Sagacity
│  │  │  ├─ History
│  │  │  │  └─ HistoryContent.ts
│  │  │  ├─ Management
│  │  │  │  └─ ManagementContent.ts
│  │  │  └─ SagacityContent.ts
│  │  ├─ Support
│  │  │  └─ supportHome.ts
│  │  └─ Terminal
│  │     └─ terminalHome.ts
│  ├─ index.css
│  ├─ main.tsx
│  ├─ pages
│  │  ├─ Configuration
│  │  │  ├─ BusinessUnits
│  │  │  │  ├─ BusinessUnits
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ Create
│  │  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  │  └─ SupportContacts
│  │  │  │     └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ Merchants
│  │  │  │  ├─ BillingGroupChains
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ BillingGroupDisbursementHold
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ BillingGroups
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ Edit
│  │  │  │  │  │  └─ [id].tsx
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ FeeTemplates
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ PaymentChannels
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ RelationshipManager
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  ├─ ODFIs
│  │  │  │  ├─ BankExpenses
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ Create
│  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ ExpenseBatch
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ FinancialInstitution
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ Create
│  │  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ RoutingNumbers
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  ├─ Partners
│  │  │  │  ├─ Create
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  │  ├─ Details
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ Profiles
│  │  │  │  ├─ APIProfiles
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ ExternalUsers
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ HeartlandUsers
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  ├─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  └─ System
│  │  │     ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │     └─ styles.module.css
│  │  ├─ Home
│  │  │  ├─ About
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  ├─ Contact
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  ├─ Faq
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  ├─ HealthCheck
│  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ Tutorial
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  │  └─ VersionHistory
│  │  │     └─ index.tsx
│  │  ├─ Sagacity
│  │  │  ├─ History
│  │  │  │  ├─ AuthenticationRequests
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ BankAccounts
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ Consumers
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ FailedAPICalls
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ History
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ Statistics
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ VerificationRequests
│  │  │  │     └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ Management
│  │  │  │  ├─ BusinessUnits
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ Configure
│  │  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ Create
│  │  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ Details
│  │  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ Edit
│  │  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ GIACTInvoices
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ Global
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ Management
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ Merchants
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ Users
│  │  │  │     └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  ├─ Support
│  │  │  ├─ ACHFiles
│  │  │  │  ├─ ACHEntryFinder
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ ACHFiles
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ ACHRejects
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ Automation
│  │  │  │  ├─ Alerts
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ Jobs
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ Subscriptions
│  │  │  │     ├─ Create
│  │  │  │     │  └─ Index.tsx
│  │  │  │     └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ Bulwark
│  │  │  │  ├─ Bulwark
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ RiskRuleConfiguration
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ RiskRuleEnforcement
│  │  │  │     └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ Consumers
│  │  │  │  ├─ Blacklist
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ Consumers
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ ProvisionalWhitelist
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ Whitelist
│  │  │  │     └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ Invoices
│  │  │  │  ├─ BillingGroup
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ Partner
│  │  │  │     └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ Logging
│  │  │  │  ├─ Emails
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ FailedApiCalls
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ Returns
│  │  │  │  ├─ Exceptions
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ NoticeOfChange
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ Reinitiations
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ ReturnDetails
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  ├─ ReturnFiles
│  │  │  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  │  └─ ReturnReconciliations
│  │  │  │     └─ index.tsx
│  │  │  └─ styles.module.css
│  │  └─ Terminal
│  │     ├─ index.tsx
│  │     ├─ styles.module.css
│  │     └─ VirtualTerminal
│  │        └─ index.tsx
│  ├─ Utils
│  │  ├─ Enums
│  │  │  ├─ MerchantTypeId.ts
│  │  │  ├─ ODFI.ts
│  │  │  ├─ RelationshipManager.ts
│  │  │  ├─ States.ts
│  │  │  └─ SupportContactId.ts
│  │  ├─ Func
│  │  └─ Interfaces
│  │     ├─ Configuration
│  │     │  ├─ Merchants
│  │     │  │  ├─ BillingGroupChains
│  │     │  │  │  └─ BillingGroupChains.ts
│  │     │  │  ├─ BillingGroups
│  │     │  │  │  └─ BillingGroupCreate.ts
│  │     │  │  ├─ FeeTemplate
│  │     │  │  │  └─ FeeTemplate.ts
│  │     │  │  ├─ Partners
│  │     │  │  │  └─ Partners.ts
│  │     │  │  └─ RelationshipManagers
│  │     │  │     └─ RelationshipManagers.ts
│  │     │  └─ Partners
│  │     └─ NavItems.ts
│  └─ vite-env.d.ts
├─ tsconfig.json
├─ tsconfig.node.json
└─ vite.config.ts

```
````

Answer (score 1):

What you have (with the `index.ts`) is totally fine and a typical pattern. However, I would tweak this by moving the component code into a separate file next to `index.ts` then import this and export it in the `index.ts`. So for example, for `ArrowIcon` you'd have `ArrowIcon.tsx` and `index.tsx` and `index.tsx` would export everything from `ArrowIcon.tsx`.

My reasons for that are:

- Tends to be a bit easier to navigate to the component with ctrl+p in vscode (or any IDE's "go to file" functionality).
- If you want that component to have sister components or maybe extra utils etc you can put them in their own file in the same folder and export them from the index file. The dev using these components does not usually care (so would use the index to grab it), but this allows all the different files you might have to optionally be imported granularly by targeting the actual file if the dev wants. This can be useful in testing scenarios or if wanting to reduce bundle sizes/have better code splitting.

Here's an [example in the popular Chakra lib](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/tree/main/packages/components/avatar/src).

Also, I wouldn't fret over this issue. It really doesn't matter much what way you pick, just pick one and be consistent.

Comment: Isn't the problem with strategies like this is that the barrel file is fully loaded, thus if you are only using 1 component, you still pay the freight for all of them?